# Get country from people and groups field using rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, odata

I was able to get details from people and groups using rest api and with the help of the below link.

https://ajaznusrat.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/using-the-sharepoint-user-type-field-people-or-group-in-list-definition/

But i am not able to figure out how to extract country and city column from people and groups column.

https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/eforms/hrd//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Mid-Year Review')/Items?$select=ID,Title,City,Office,Department,Country,Division/Title, Employee/FirstName,Employee/LastName&$expand= Division/ID,Employee/ID

the above gives all but country and city details. How do i get that details as well.

Comment: You want get Employee country?

Answer (score 0):

Not all user profile properties that we could get from people column.
[image]

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31210.sharepoint-2013-get-user-details-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api.aspx